# visual studio 2010: dependency graph

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have VS 2010 professional edition. What can I do to use "Dependency Graph". I do not have "architectural" edition. Is there a FREE plugin that I could use. If not, are there any FREE 3rd party tools that could help me do the same thing.

Thanks

Comment: Not a pretty graph, but see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43374622/64334

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dependency-analyser can help you.

http://code.google.com/p/dependency-analyser/

[image]

Answer (score 14):

I needed something similar, but didn't want to pay for (or install) a tool to do it. I [created a quick PowerShell script that goes through the project references](https://blog.dantup.com/2012/05/free-dependency-graph-generation-using-powershell-and-yuml/) and spits them out in a [yuml.me](https://yuml.me/) friendly-format instead:

```
Function Get-ProjectReferences ($rootFolder)
{
    $projectFiles = Get-ChildItem $rootFolder -Filter *.csproj -Recurse
    $ns = @{ defaultNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" }

    $projectFiles | ForEach-Object {
        $projectFile = $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
        $projectName = $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName
        $projectXml = [xml](Get-Content $projectFile)
        
        $projectReferences = $projectXml | Select-Xml '//defaultNamespace:ProjectReference/defaultNamespace:Name' -Namespace $ns | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "#text"
        
        $projectReferences | ForEach-Object {
            "[" + $projectName + "] -> [" + $_ + "]"
        }
    }
}

Get-ProjectReferences "C:\Users\DanTup\Documents\MyProject" | Out-File "C:\Users\DanTup\Documents\MyProject\References.txt"
```

[image: Sample Graph]
<sub>(source: [yuml.me](https://yuml.me/4f30e632))</sub>

Comment: major kudo's for this approach

Answer (score 3):

http://dependencyvisualizer.codeplex.com/ might help. You didn't say if you need something that goes beyond project-level dependencies.

Comment: The downloadable version does not support VS2010. You will need to compile from source if you want to analyse VS2010 +

Answer (score 2):

You have also the **[VS Solution Dependency Viewer](http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/visual-studio-solution-dependency-visualizer/)** which supports **VS2010** and is *free for freeware/evaluation* projects. You can download it directly from [GForge: VS Solution Dependency Viewer](http://gforge.devio.at/projects/vsslndepvis/) project page.

Answer (score 1):

The NDepend tool does both dependency graph and dependency matrix (objectively 100x faster than VS2010 graph actually) but it is not free.

However you can [download and use free trial](http://www.ndepend.com/NDependDownload.aspx) for a while. And if you are working on an OSS project, contact us and we'll be happy to sponsor your OSS project with a free license (I am part of the tool team):

[More on NDepend Dependency Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx)
[image]

[More on NDepend Dependency Matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx):
[image]