# In C#, how to find chain of circular dependency?

Tags: c#, circular-dependency

This error usually occurs when one deployment project contains the project outputs of a second deployment project, and the second project contains the outputs of the first project.

I have a method that check circular dependency. In input, we have a dictionary that contains, for example, `<"A", < "B", "C" >>` and  `<"B", < "A", "D" >>`, this means that `A` depends on `B` and `C` and we have circular dependency with `A->B`.

But usually we have a more complex situation, with a chain of dependency.
How to modify this method to find a chain of dependency? For example, I want to have a variable that contains chain `A->B->A`, rather than class `A` has a conflict with class `B`.

```
private void FindDependency(IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> serviceDependence)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why doesn't your algorithm work? What's the problem with it? We're not here to write code for you.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I update my code. But it works slowly

Comment: Topological sort could help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43374622/64334

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A simple way to find cycles in a graph is to use a recursive depth-first graph-coloring algorithm in which nodes are marked as "visiting" or "visited".  If, when visiting a node, you find it is already in the "visiting" state, you have a cycle.  Nodes marked as "visited" can be skipped.  For instance:

```
public class DependencyExtensions
{
    enum VisitState
    {
        NotVisited,
        Visiting,
        Visited
    };

    public static TValue ValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue defaultValue)
    {
        TValue value;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
            return value;
        return defaultValue;
    }

    static void DepthFirstSearch<T>(T node, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> lookup, List<T> parents, Dictionary<T, VisitState> visited, List<List<T>> cycles)
    {
        var state = visited.ValueOrDefault(node, VisitState.NotVisited);
        if (state == VisitState.Visited)
            return;
        else if (state == VisitState.Visiting)
        {
            // Do not report nodes not included in the cycle.
            cycles.Add(parents.Concat(new[] { node }).SkipWhile(parent => !EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(parent, node)).ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            visited[node] = VisitState.Visiting;
            parents.Add(node);
            foreach (var child in lookup(node))
                DepthFirstSearch(child, lookup, parents, visited, cycles);
            parents.RemoveAt(parents.Count - 1);
            visited[node] = VisitState.Visited;
        }
    }

    public static List<List<T>> FindCycles<T>(this IEnumerable<T> nodes, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> edges)
    {
        var cycles = new List<List<T>>();
        var visited = new Dictionary<T, VisitState>();
        foreach (var node in nodes)
            DepthFirstSearch(node, edges, new List<T>(), visited, cycles);
        return cycles;
    }

    public static List<List<T>> FindCycles<T, TValueList>(this IDictionary<T, TValueList> listDictionary)
        where TValueList : class, IEnumerable<T>
    {
        return listDictionary.Keys.FindCycles(key => listDictionary.ValueOrDefault(key, null) ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>());
    }
}
```

Then, you could use it like:

```
        var serviceDependence = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
        {
            { "A", new List<string> { "A" }},
            { "B", new List<string> { "C", "D" }},
            { "D", new List<string> { "E" }},
            { "E", new List<string> { "F", "Q" }},
            { "F", new List<string> { "D" }},
        };
        var cycles = serviceDependence.FindCycles();
        Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cycles, Formatting.Indented));
        foreach (var cycle in cycles)
        {
            serviceDependence[cycle[cycle.Count - 2]].Remove(cycle[cycle.Count - 1]);
        }
        Debug.Assert(serviceDependence.FindCycles().Count == 0);
```

**Update**

Your question has been updated to request the "most efficient algorithm" for finding cyclic dependencies.  The code in the original answer is recursive, so there's a chance of a `StackOverflowException` for dependency chains thousands of levels deep.  Here's a non-recursive version with an explicit stack variable:

```
public static class DependencyExtensions
{
    enum VisitState
    {
        NotVisited,
        Visiting,
        Visited
    };

    public static TValue ValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue defaultValue)
    {
        TValue value;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
            return value;
        return defaultValue;
    }

    private static void TryPush<T>(T node, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> lookup, Stack<KeyValuePair<T, IEnumerator<T>>> stack, Dictionary<T, VisitState> visited, List<List<T>> cycles)
    {
        var state = visited.ValueOrDefault(node, VisitState.NotVisited);
        if (state == VisitState.Visited)
            return;
        else if (state == VisitState.Visiting)
        {
            Debug.Assert(stack.Count > 0);
            var list = stack.Select(pair => pair.Key).TakeWhile(parent => !EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(parent, node)).ToList();
            list.Add(node);
            list.Reverse();
            list.Add(node);
            cycles.Add(list);
        }
        else
        {
            visited[node] = VisitState.Visiting;
            stack.Push(new KeyValuePair<T, IEnumerator<T>>(node, lookup(node).GetEnumerator()));
        }
    }

    static List<List<T>> FindCycles<T>(T root, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> lookup, Dictionary<T, VisitState> visited)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<KeyValuePair<T, IEnumerator<T>>>();
        var cycles = new List<List<T>>();

        TryPush(root, lookup, stack, visited, cycles);
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var pair = stack.Peek();
            if (!pair.Value.MoveNext())
            {
                stack.Pop();                    
                visited[pair.Key] = VisitState.Visited;
                pair.Value.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                TryPush(pair.Value.Current, lookup, stack, visited, cycles);
            }
        }
        return cycles;
    }

    public static List<List<T>> FindCycles<T>(this IEnumerable<T> nodes, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> edges)
    {
        var cycles = new List<List<T>>();
        var visited = new Dictionary<T, VisitState>();
        foreach (var node in nodes)
            cycles.AddRange(FindCycles(node, edges, visited));
        return cycles;
    }

    public static List<List<T>> FindCycles<T, TValueList>(this IDictionary<T, TValueList> listDictionary)
        where TValueList : class, IEnumerable<T>
    {
        return listDictionary.Keys.FindCycles(key => listDictionary.ValueOrDefault(key, null) ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>());
    }
}
```

This should be reasonably efficient at `N*log(N) + E` where `N` is the number of nodes and `E` is the number of edges.  The `Log(N)` comes from building the `visited` hash table and could be eliminated by making each node remember its `VisitState`.  This seems reasonably performant; in the following test harness, the time to find 17897 cycles of average length 4393 in 10000 nodes with 125603 total dependencies is around 10.2 seconds:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public static void TestBig()
    {
        var elapsed = TestBig(10000);
        Debug.WriteLine(elapsed.ToString());
    }

    static string GetName(int i)
    {
        return "ServiceDependence" + i.ToString();
    }

    public static TimeSpan TestBig(int count)
    {
        var serviceDependence = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        for (int iItem = 0; iItem < count; iItem++)
        {
            var name = GetName(iItem);
            // Add several forward references.
            for (int iRef = iItem - 1; iRef > 0; iRef = iRef / 2)
                serviceDependence.Add(name, GetName(iRef));
            // Add some backwards references.
            if (iItem > 0 && (iItem % 5 == 0))
                serviceDependence.Add(name, GetName(iItem + 5));
        }

        // Add one backwards reference that will create some extremely long cycles.
        serviceDependence.Add(GetName(1), GetName(count - 1));

        List<List<string>> cycles;

        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        try
        {
            cycles = serviceDependence.FindCycles();
        }
        finally
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
        }

        var elapsed = stopwatch.Elapsed;

        var averageLength = cycles.Average(l => (double)l.Count);
        var total = serviceDependence.Values.Sum(l => l.Count);

        foreach (var cycle in cycles)
        {
            serviceDependence[cycle[cycle.Count - 2]].Remove(cycle[cycle.Count - 1]);
        }
        Debug.Assert(serviceDependence.FindCycles().Count == 0);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Time to find {0} cycles of average length {1} in {2} nodes with {3} total dependencies: {4}", cycles.Count, averageLength, count, total, elapsed));
        Console.ReadLine();
        System.Environment.Exit(0);

        return elapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how can I call FindCycles() without parameters?

Comment: @Anatoly - I implemented it as an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) which is how it appears to be a method on `IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>`.

Comment: If you use `int`, you will get a better performance by doing a concrete number implementation instead of using generics (this will avoid boxing)... also using `!=` instead of `!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals` https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/making-dotnet-applications-faster/table-of-contents

Answer (score 8):

Build a dictionary with all the direct dependencies of each of the inputs. For each of those, add all unique indirect dependencies (e.g. go over each of the dependencies of the given item, and if it doesn't exist for the parent, add it). Repeat as long as you make at least one change to the dictionary. If there's an item that has itself in it's dependencies, it's a cyclical dependency :)

This is relatively inefficient, of course, but it's quite simple and easy to understand. If you were creating a compiler, you would probably just build a directed graph of all the dependencies, and search for paths in that - you can find a lot of ready algorithms for finding a path in a directed graph.

Answer (score 0):

Topological sort is the way to do that. I have a implementation in Vb.net [here](https://gist.github.com/marcelodeaguiar/5508950)