# What is the algorithm to find circular dependency in the project?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need to find circular dependency between classes and I immediately remember two things from the "Algorithms and Data Structures" course:

1)Finding a Loop in a Singly Linked List (Floyd’s Cycle-Finding Algorithm)

2)Depth-first search

So, I have a method that check circular dependency

```
 private void FindDependency(IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> serviceDependence)
```

In input, we have a dictionary that contains, for example,  `<"A", < "B", "C" >>` and  `<"B", < "A", "D" >>`, this means that class `A` depends on class `B` and `C`.  In the output, we have a circular dependency between `A->B`(in the more complex situation it will be a chain of dependency).

Which algorithms should I use and why?

Comment: building a dfs-tree of your dependency graph and finding back edges would work fine.

Comment: this is a duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703972/in-c-how-to-find-chain-of-circular-dependency

Comment: in case you don't want only to check for those cycles but also do a topological sort: those usually find cycles anyway (per failure)

Comment: If you don't want to use standard algorithms then try with linq: `var result = serviceDependence.Where(c => serviceDependence.Any(x => x.Value.Any(y => y == c.Key && c.Value.Any(z => z == x.Key)))).ToList();`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri What algorithms do you mean? And where I can find their implementations?

Comment: Haven't you just been provided with a link on your dublicate question with an answer?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri In my previous question we discuss my solution that work O(n^2). In this question, I'm trying to find the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: And difference between 1)Floyd’s Cycle-Finding Algorithm and 2) Depth-first search algorithms

Comment: Floyd's cycle-finding algorithm has the remarkable property of using only constant space, but it only works on *lists* -- it won't work on a general DAG.  Depth-first search is the way to go here (or topological ordering, which is possibly something you will need to do anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can transform the dictionary in a graph you could do a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) on it.
If there is a circular dependency the sorting will fail, else it will succeed.