# Newtonsoft.Net Json callback on each class deserialize completely

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, json.net, ef-core-2.1

Description of the issue:

I want to validate the relation between classes in deserialized JSON object on the server. as an example: Claimed foreign key is correct between class A and class B.

A:

```
{
"Id": "z",
"B": [
    {
        "Id": "x",
    },
    {
        "Id": "y",
    }
   ]
}
```

In this case i want to figure out whether class A with Id "Z", has a valid relation to Class B with id "x" and "y" , And this can be deeper and deeper ... so B can have several inner relation and must be checked after B has been completely deserialized

I Don't want to write a recursive function, because i think it has lot of performance penalty for a server side program.

Some of property checks can be easily done using `Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.IValueProvider` but the problem is, i can't find out when a class has been completely deserialized ( all required properties has their own value in last `public void SetValue (object target, object value)` call , some of them may have nothing at all and this feature is different for each class)

This part of server has been fully written with reflection and its completely generic.

So the question is:
How can i find out this `SetValue` is the last SetValue call for this object? (for example object key is always the last call or something like it)

Or any other way for me to check this relation before `IdentityDbContext.Update`

Thanks

Comment: You don't want to write a recursive function because of performance concerns but have no problem using reflection?

Comment: are you looking for the `[OnDeserialized]` callback? https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm

Comment: @Abion47 it’s about how to write a general purpose server with minimum penalty

Comment: @MarcGravell any other way with out modifying models ?

Comment: Recursion isn't inherently any less performant than plain old iteration. If it's the right tool for the job, use it.

Comment: Don't make implementation decisions based on uninformed guesses of how it will perform.  Instead, write your implementation in the way that makes the most sense, then *measure* the performance to see if it is acceptable.  If it is not, *then* work on improving it.

Comment: 1) If you are concerned about the performance of recursion, you could use as explicit stack & graph coloring algorithm such as the one shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29707338/3744182) to [In C#, how to find chain of circular dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29703972/3744182).  However, recursion is only problematic for *deep* trees; does that apply here?

Comment: 2) If you don't want to modify your models you could add a callback to [`JsonContract.OnDeserializedCallbacks`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract_OnDeserializedCallbacks.htm) with a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples).